# Lord Harkon Disappears

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

After arriving at the castle, Lord Harkon gives you the option to become a vampire lord, but when I accept the offer Lord Harkon disappears. The cut scene continues though and I have the power to transform. However, I can't leave the castle without speaking to Lord Harkon. How can I find him or make him reappear?

Answer (score 3):

I discovered the problem was I had already been infected as a vampire and for some reason that was causing problems in the script. Simply taking a potion of cure diseases fixed the problem.

Comment: Have you managed to reproduce the bug while infected?

Comment: Yes, Several times. I'm not sure if this is a problem my game in particular or the game itself.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on PC, try the command `02003ba8.moveto player` (assuming Dawnguard has ID 02 in your load order, which it should) to move him to you; if that doesn't work try `prid 02003ba8`, `disable`, `enable`, `kill`, `resurrect`, `moveto player`. If you're not playing on PC your best bet is to reload to a previous save.